# raise exception and return response

Tags: django, exception, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I need to raise exception inside the `validate()` method of a Serializer. So I did something like below,

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = SampleModel

    def validate(self, attrs):
        foo_value = attrs['foo']
        if foo_value > 100:
            raise ValueError("foo_value cant be grater than 100")
        return attrs
```

It raising an exception, but as ***server error***.

How can I raise the exception and safely return some message to the API response?

Comment: You should raise a `serializers.ValidationError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should raise a `ValidationError` instead:

```
class SampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = SampleModel

    def validate(self, attrs):
        foo_value = attrs['foo']
        if foo_value > 100:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("foo_value cant be grater than 100")
        return attrs
```

It will then, as described in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data) raise a `HTTP 400 Bad` Request responses by default.